# Finding the root of a scalar function of 3 variables which is a an interpolation of data?

Tags: numerics

Dear Stackexchange community, I am puzzling the following question:

I have energy values on a three dimensional grid. More precisely, I have the solutions from a band structure calculation on a three dimensional grid of 61x61x61 k-points. I need to to find the Fermi surface, which is the points in this 3D space where the energy is equal to the Fermi energy which in units of Rydberg is 0.866925.

I look up values in table which are close to 0.866925 and pick surrounding points, for example, the point {1, 1, 18}:

```
gp={{{1, 1, 18}, 0.866961}, {{0, 1, 18}, 0.867079}, {{2, 0, 18}, 0.866751}, {{1, 0, 18}, 0.867091}, {{1, 2, 18}, 0.866575}, {{1, 1, 17}, 0.869358}, {{1, 1, 19}, 0.864441}}
```

I then interpolate on these points:

```
fgp = Interpolation[gp]
```

I define a region in which I want the solutions:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 2 && 17 <= z <= 19, {x, y, z}];
```

And ask for the solution of the interpolation function being the Fermi energy:

```
Solve[fgp[x, y, z] - 0.866925 == 0 && {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], {x, y, z}]
```

Which does not give me a solution but an error.

It also fails to compute anything if I replace == with a lower limit such as <0.00001.

Obviously, I am doing it wrong, but why and how?

There is a solution in the region as:

```
fgp[1.4, 1.4, 17.85]
```

is 0.866928 for example.

Answer (score 4):

You may get a solution using "FindInstance":

```
sol = FindInstance[
   fgp[x, y, z] - 0.866925 == 
     0 && {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], {x, y, z}][[1]]
(* {x -> 1.15057, y -> 779/501, z -> 8962/501}{x -> 1.15057, y -> 779/501, z -> 8962/501} *)
```

To test this, you may write:

```
fgp[x, y, z] - 0.866925 /. sol
(* 0. *)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. What is the difference between Solve and FindInstance?

Comment: Solve tries to find all solutions. FindInstance is happy if it finds a single one.